# Cannot access to req.body inside middlewares

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I actually have a very tiny app in node.js with Express, and I can't access to req.body.

This is my `app.js` code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    middleware = require('./middleware'),
    mysql  = require('mysql'),
    app = express();

app.use(middleware.authenticate);
app.use(middleware.getScope);

app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
```

And the file with the middlewares:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    mysql  = require('mysql');

function authenticate(req, res, next){
   console.log(req.body);
    next();
}

function getScope(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
}

module.exports.authenticate = authenticate;
module.exports.getScope = getScope;
```

In all cases req.body is `undefined`.

I'm sending data throw Postman with `x-www-form-urlencoded` protocol, in this case is a must.

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: You need the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `body-parser` to express:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Check **Request** here http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

And perhaps a POST route could help too:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```